# Explaining a proof of Euler's theorem

Tags: symmetry, derivatives

Can someone please explain the question marked extrapolation in the following image?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression after the question mark comes from differentiating $\lambda^n f(q)$ with respect to $\lambda$. Everything before the question mark came from differentiating $f(\lambda\,q)$ using the chain rule. The assumption of homogeneity makes the two equal, and setting $\lambda=1$ yields the desired identity.

Comment: Ahhh, of course. Thanks!